# TypeScript - why is the spread operator used in map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

```
return items.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      score: Math.round((item.rate / 100) * 5)
    }));
```

I know that it changes `score` value for each object `items`. But why there is `...item`?

What is benefit to use it?

Is it equal to this?:

```
return items.map(item => ({
          item.score: Math.round((item.rate / 100) * 5);
          return item;
        }));
```

Comment: It's called the spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I know how it is named, but is it necessary in this case? How much it costs about memery?

Comment: *"I know that it changes `score` value for each object `items`."* **No**, it does not change any items, that's the point. It makes a copy. Read up on the topic of *immutable objects* or *immutability* in general and its purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what previous answers suggest, notice that the spread operator is spreading the contents of `item` into another curly brace.

It's shallow copying the contents of `item` into that new object but replacing with the new value for `score`.

It is a memory efficient copy process and makes for very good code readability. It is similar to what you suggested.

It only provides better syntactic sugar in that context. I would advise you to consider using the spread operator a bit more if only for this purpose as well as its other use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is useful, if you want to create a shallow copy of the existing values, and update the object/array [immutably](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns).

One frequent usage of the spread syntax would be when you are using [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) for React.js or [NgRX](https://ngrx.io/) for Angular.

In the case of the code you have provided,

```
return items.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  score: Math.round((item.rate / 100) * 5)
}));
```

The resulting array will be a shallow copy of the `items` array alongside the original properties/values, followed by the updated values of the `score` property within each object of the `items` array.

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to

```
Array.prototype.map.call(items, function(item) {
  return Object.assign({}, item, {
    score: Math.round((item.rate / 100) * 5)
  });
});
```

the idea of this approach is to create new array and for each item of the old create to create a new object containing all of the old's properties and a score property. If the `score` is present on the item (old array's entry it will be overwritten on the new object)

Answer (score 1):

This is the spread operator, basically what the function is doing, is taking each item, mapping it to an object containing: a full clone of the item, and the score

```
{ item, score }
```

while your proposed function will only return the item object with an added attribute to it `score`, and also add that attribute to the element in the original `items` array, as you're modifying the referenced object, not a copy of it.

which to use? well that depends on your needs.